# Good Practices for Auction E-Commerce - Should I store Credit Cards Details?

Tags: e-commerce, payment-gateway, payment, credit-card, marketplace

I am sorry if this wasn't a good place to ask a question like this, but since I always got help from Stackoverflow I though I could get some answer to my problem.

So here is the thing, I am building a e-commerce website like many famous websites over there, where you can make bid offers for items on the market.

The thing I want to be sure is that when someone place a bid for some item, they can not turn back on their word, because if they get accepted the money should be withdrawn from their bank accounts, do you get what I mean?

Because I want the merchant to be safe if they accept a offer they want the money, and they don't want to look for another legit offer.

So how can I accomplish this?
Should I ask the credit card details when they make the bid offer and only make the withdraw operation from their accounts if the their offer was accepted by the merchant? [using some automated trigger on my database of course]

If this is not the best practice to accomplish this, which is the one??

I am really new into payment methods and I just started doing my search for Payment Gateways (maybe they offer me this functionality... I don't know?!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should never store credit card details, and have the details is not really any guarantee of getting paid since the card could just be canceled.

What you are probably looking for is for Authorization and delayed capture (depending on the timeline you are looking at). Different payment processors have different time requirements around how long you can hold an authorization. In general you would make a request with the API to Authorize the charges (kind of like a 'hold' on your credit card) and then later you would either cancel or Capture, where the funds would be transferred. See more info about the process and Square's API here: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/delayed-capture-transactions/

Comment: Thank you tristansokol, someone told me that I could use Stripe for this purpose? thank you in advance!

Comment: Square, Stripe, PayPal, Authorize.net could all probably meet your needs here.